# Creating a dependant picklist in Javascript survey monkey api

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, surveymonkey, picklist

I'm using the survey monkey PHP API to retrieve a list of surveys in the account. Passing in a $params variable, I can retrieve the survey ID and the survey name. Using the response, I am building two separate picklists as shown below:

```
function build_picklist($survey, $name) {
    global $workbooks;

    $picklist = "<select name=\"{$name}\">";
    $picklist. = "<option value=\"\" selected=\"selected\">Select...</option>";

    foreach($survey['data']['surveys'] as & $entry) {
        if ($name == 'survey_list') {
            $entry = $entry['title'];
        } else {
            $entry = $entry['survey_id'];
        }

        $label = htmlentities($entry);
        $picklist. = "<option value=\"{$entry}\">{$label}</option>";
    }
    $picklist. = "</select>";
    $workbooks - > log('Picklist HTML', $picklist);

    return $picklist;
}
```

This works nicely and my form displays a list of surveys on the account and another list of the id's for those surveys. Using the code below:

```
    <html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#integrate_button").click(function(){
                $(this).val("Integrating...")
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://secure.workbooks.com/resources/=UzN4IDN/survey_monkey.css">
<title>Integrate with Survey Monkey</title>
<body>
<div id="container" align="center">
    <div id="header">
        <img src="https://secure.workbooks.com/resources/=UzN4IDN/sm_logo.jpg" height="100" width="200"/>
    </div>
    <div id="nav">
        <p>Below is a list of the Surveys on your account. Pick one to integrate with.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="section1">
        <form method="POST" action="https://secure.workbooks.com/process/=gTOwIjN/Survey_Monkey" id="pg2_form">
            <p>Which Survey would you like to integrate Workbooks with?<p>
            <p>{$survey_picklist}</p>
            <p>Survey ID: <p>
            <p>{$survey_id}</p>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="section2">
       <p><input type="submit" name="integrate" id="integrate_button" form="pg2_form" value="Integrate with Survey Monkey"/></p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What I'd like to do is link the two together so when I select an option in the survey name field, it shows the corresponding ID for that survey in the other picklist.

My guess is I'd need to use Jquery/JS to achieve this but I can't seem to find any useful examples on the internet.

I'm new to Jquery/JS and don't really know how to use it that much, things I've done in the past have worked by pure fluke! Please be nice! :)

Comment: This might be useful to connect to their API and try out responses https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api_console

Comment: could you post relevant html code here

Comment: Added. I hope that helps...

Comment: where is the jsfiddle link

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/o6zgwb64/ You can use this link, although the picklist is generated using PHP so i'm not sure it's what you need...